# Probability of collision of SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, uuid

I am using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)` in order to create unique ids in my system that are URL safe.

I would like to know how to calculate the probability of collision? I am inserting about 10.000 of those ids into an array, and I want to avoid checking if one of the keys is already in the array, but I also want to make sure that are not repeated? What are the chances?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a good approximation of this probability (which relates to the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)). If there are `k` potential values and `n` are sampled, the probability of collision is:

```
k! / (k^n * (k - n)!)
```

The [base64](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) method returns a base 64 string built from the inputted number of random bytes, not that number of random digits. Eight random bytes gives us `k = 256^8`, about `1.8446744e+19`. You are generating 10,000 of these strings, so `n = 10,000`, which gives us a probability of `2.710498492319857e-12`, which is very low.

Answer (score 7):

You do not *make something sure* by calculation of a probability, you only know how likely it might happen.

To protect yourself, just add a unique index to the database column. That ensures that you cannot store duplicate entries in your database. With such a unique index, an insertion will raise an `ActiveRecord::InvalidStatement` error in case this very unlikely (see @Andrew's answer) ever happens.

Comment: Very good point! If you need to be more than "probably" sure, the probability doesn't matter and you need validation.

Answer (score 0):

Slight adjustment to Andrew's answer, I believe the equation for probability of collision is:

```
1 - (k! / (k^n * (k - n)!))
```

Given that `k` is potential values and `n` the number of samples.
The equation:

```
k! / (k^n * (k - n)!)
```

gives the probability that there is NOT a collision -- according to the [birthday problem wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

You can sanity check this by trying a few different `n` values. More samples should naturally give a higher probability of collision.